# Screen crash when I opening firefox in Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, crash

I'm experiencing the follow screen crash when I opening Firefox after turned on my laptop. To recover normal view I need to restore and maximize it again.
It's curious, because just happen when I'm opening Firefox at first time after start up.
I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Firefox 71.0 (64-bit) with this extensions: keep note (google), Adblocker Ultimate, Simple Translate, Ublock Origin, Google TM Translator and Dark Reader.
Additionally,  dialog box, like where to save files ever open in my second monitor (yes, I'm using 2).

I'm using the same version and extensions another Windows PC and all things looks like good. It's I'm not sure if the problem is OS or Firefox.

Thank you all

[image: Problem during opening:]
[image: Problem with Dialog Box:]

Comment: Pardon my bad eyesight but I don't see the screen crash message? Or perhaps when you say "screen crash" you don't actually mean crash?

Comment: Looks like a gnome-shell crash. Watch the content of `/var/crash` to see which program is crashing. If its gnome-shell, please [edit] to add more info (gnome extensions, syslog extract...)

Comment: Thank you, guys. I'm vacation, when I back to home I'll try it...
I'm sorry @WinEunuuchs2Unix, English isn't my frist language. I wanna say the problem is black border at right side in Firefox window. For now, I've noticed it is more frequent when I'm using a second monitor (HDMI). Currently I'm using nouveau driver in my nvidia 525M in 18.04.3 LTS.